# Geothermal gradient near surface?

Tags: geothermal-heat, reference-request

Is there a good chart of the geothermal gradient but near the surface? I haven't been able to find one because they are primarily studied at larger depths, but I would like to know the equilibria at different depths within 1 kilometer.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with geothermal gradients is they are not the same everywhere. It is generally accepted that the geothermal gradient is 25-30 °C/km but there can be local variations. In [South Australia](https://energymining.sa.gov.au/geothermal/exploration_and_development/What_is_Geothermal_Energy) the gradient is generally 30° C/km, but in the deeper parts of the [Cooper Basin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_Basin) the gradient is 55-60 °C/km. [Elsewhere](https://www.ablison.com/what-is-the-geothermal-gradient/), at a depth of 200 ft the temp is 11 C. [In the UK](http://www.geoelec.eu/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/UK-deep-geothermal-resources_JBusby.pdf) the average geothermal gradient is 26 °C/km, but locally it can be in excess of 35°C/km.

With near surface depths, the [ground temperature will vary with depth according to the time of day](https://pubs.usgs.gov/bul/1172/report.pdf).

[image]

So to get an accurate geothermal map for your region would require localized data.